# SQL Beginner : Multiple where clause from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I'm very new to SQL and am not sure how to accomplish the following.

I have a list of meter IDs that have a years worth of Target and a years worth of Budget data assigned, however these are all held in the same table with an identifier (TargetType) to distinguish between Target(0) & Budget(1)

```
ID   TARGETTYPE   VALUE01   VALUE02 ...(etc up to VALUE12)
123  0            1001      1100
123  1            9000      9100
456  0            5000      5100
456  1            8000      8100
```

Desired result would be also include information from a couple of other tables  want to add that in as well

My query so far can bring through one set of data :

```
PARAMETERS 
[Utility] Text;

SELECT 
Contacts.Group,
Contacts.Site,
Points.ID,
Points.Utility,
Points.MPAN1,
Target.Value_01 AS [Target JAN],
Target.Value_02 AS [Target FEB],
Target.Value_03 AS [Target MAR],
Target.Value_04 AS [Target APR],
Target.Value_05 AS [Target MAY],
Target.Value_06 AS [Target JUN],
Target.Value_07 AS [Target JUL],
Target.Value_08 AS [Target AUG],
Target.Value_09 AS [Target SEP],
Target.Value_10 AS [Target OCT],
Target.Value_11 AS [Target NOV],
Target.Value_12 AS [Target DEC]

FROM 
((Contacts INNER JOIN Points ON Contacts.[Id] = Points.[Contacts_Id]) 
                  INNER JOIN Contracts ON Points.[Id] = Contracts.[Point_Id]) 
                  INNER JOIN Target ON Points.Id = Target.DataSetId

WHERE 
Points.UtilityType =[Utility]

ORDER BY 
Contacts.ClientGroup;
```

Desired Output
(the values would go TargetJan through to TargetDec and then BudgetJan through to BudgetDec but I've not shown for brevity):

```
Group Site     ID   Utility MPAN1    TargetJan TargetFeb etc... BudgetJan  BudgetFeb etc...      
ABC   London   123  Gas     123456    1,000     1,100           9,000      9,100
ABC   NewYork  456  Gas     ABC123    5,000     5,100           8,000      8,100
```

How can I add in the same fields but depending on the value of Target.TargetType, I'm guessing that it is a Union query, but I have no idea.

Any pointers of where to start would be gratefully received :)

---

**UPDATE #1**
Thank you for your help. I think I understand the query, however there is still a bit of odd behaviour I can't figure out.

QUERY USED

```
SELECT 
Points.ID,

  SUM(CASE WHEN Target.TargetType = '0' THEN Target.Value_01 else 0 end) AS [TGT JAN],
  SUM(CASE WHEN Target.TargetType = '0' THEN Target.Value_02 else 0 end) AS [TGT FEB],

FROM 
((Contacts INNER JOIN Points ON Contacts.[Id] = Points.[Contacts_Id]) 
              INNER JOIN Contracts ON Points.[Id] = Contracts.[Point_Id] )
              INNER JOIN Target ON Points.Id = Target.DataSetId

GROUP BY
Points.ID

ORDER BY
Points.ID;
```

Where my data row only has one Target.Type then the query returns as desired:
RAW DATA

```
ID     TARGETTYPE   VALUE_01   VALUE_02 
10079  0            7642      5735
```

RESULT

```
ID    TGTJAN   TGTFEB
10079 7642    5735
```

However ... If I have an ID with 2 or more TargetTypes then the Value output is being  multiplied by 6. 

RAW DATA

```
ID     TARGETTYPE   VALUE_01   VALUE_02 
7423   0            58339     57441
7423   1            1663      1637
```

RESULT

```
ID    TGTJAN   TGTFEB
7423  350034   344646
```

I have experimented and removed the INNER JOIN to the contacts table (although I will need that join) and then it all works as expected ???? So why is the Contacts JOIN causing this issue ?

Please put me out of my misery as I can not work out what is going on !

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of your desired results?

Comment: And please tell us which DBMS you are using "*SQL*" is just a query language, not a specific DBMS product. And your example is using non-standard syntax (looks like SQL Server/T-SQL)

Comment: I believe it's SQL Server as that's what's mentioned in the help document

Comment: Union would work, and then sort by group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference I have solved this problem by rewriting the joins and changing the way the data is held so I don't need to reference the Contracts table, which is redudant and probably contributed to my bizarre x by 6 problem.

```
SELECT 
Points.ID,

  SUM(CASE WHEN Target.TargetType = '0' THEN Target.Value_01 else 0 end) AS [TGT kWh JAN],
  SUM(CASE WHEN Target.TargetType = '0' THEN Target.Value_02 else 0 end) AS [TGT kWh FEB],

  SUM(CASE WHEN Target.TargetType = '1' THEN Target.Value_01 else 0 end) AS [BUD kWh JAN],
  SUM(CASE WHEN Target.TargetType = '1' THEN Target.Value_02 else 0 end) AS [BUD kWh FEB]

FROM (Contacts INNER JOIN Points ON Contacts.Id = Points.Contacts_Id)  
                       INNER JOIN Target ON Points.Id = Target.DataSetId

GROUP BY
Points.ID

ORDER BY
Points.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a select case syntax?

```
select
...
sum(case when Target.TargetType = 'Target' then Target.Value_01 else 0 end) AS [Target JAN],
sum(case when Target.TargetType = 'Budget' then Target.Value_01 else 0 end) AS [Budget JAN],
...
group by
--all fields in the select list which are not aggregates
```

Comment: Thank you, this has definitely given me a starting point !

However,
1) I'm getting errors when I use the SUM portion of the query
2) I'm getting duplicate lines for each ID rather than have the values in one line per ID

Comment: ERROR is Column 'Points.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
SELECT
Points.ID,
Contacts.Text_7,
Contacts.Name,

sum(case when Target.TargetType = '0' then Target.Value_01 else 0 end) AS [TGT kWh JAN]

FROM 
((Contacts INNER JOIN Points ON Contacts.[Id] = Points.[Contacts_Id]) 
                  INNER JOIN Contracts ON Points.[Id] = Contracts.[Point_Id]) 
                  INNER JOIN Target ON Points.Id = Target.DataSetId

ORDER BY
Contacts.Text_7;

GROUP BY
Points.ID,
Contacts.Text_7,
Contacts.Name;

Comment: I've already told you in my example: you have to put all fields to the group by clause which are in the select list which are not aggregates

Comment: Now I see your error: 1: Remove the ; sign from between the order by and the group clause and the right order is group by than order by